# get the facebook post's likes with their created time

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get analytics of a facebook page's post on the basis of the the time they created. In case of comments when we call **{object_id}/comments** it gives created time with other related data but the same doesn't works for likes.
Is there anyway to get likes with the time?

Answer (score 0):

You would expect that something like the following would work:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{post_id}/likes?fiends=id,name,time
```

But using the [FQL Like table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/) as reference, it doesn't look like time is available as a friend. It is however supported with [Comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/) as you've found. I don't think it's possible to have a timestamp for Likes, even though Facebook is likely to be storing it.